# How to control scrolling speed and ease?

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, scroll, user-experience

In this site https://freenode.linux.community/channel-rules/ you can notice that the scrolling is not the default one..
Try to scroll fast to the bottom and then to the top.. You can feel that the scrolling is not as the default you can feel on other sites..

Can anyone know how to do that?

Comment: by looking a the scrollbar, i can see it use the nicescroll script, maybe you could look it's doc to find if it can help you, i don't know if there is a pure-javascript-cross-browser way to do that easily though

Comment: Yep, I thought that this affects only the aesthetics.. I cannot figure out which script (or even css rules) allow to control the scrolling though..